# Docker pull fails with Error 'not found'

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am looking for some suggestions on debugging and root causing an issue on one of my nodes in a Kubernetes cluster.

The issue is any docker pull operation on that node fails with a 'not found' error.

here is what I have tried so far.

1. Checked that the private registry is ok and works from other nodes.
2. Checked docker daemon is running, other docker operations work
3. No issues with networking (dig  works,  curl -v     https://registry.abc.xyz.com.symcpe.net:443https:// --> returns HTTP/1.1 200 OK)

I have not tried restarting the docker daemon, frankly I am scared to do it since there could be production pods on this node.

Any docker pull operation fails on that node with a 'not found' error. It is not an issue with the registry as the operation works from other nodes.

Tried both with our private registry and docker.io

```
# docker -D pull  registry.abc.xyz.com/behzad_dastur/brokermon:0.1
Trying to pull repository registry.abc.xyz.com/brd/brokermon 
... 0.1: Pulling from brd/brokermon
not found
Error: image brd/brokermon:0.1 not found

# docker pull alpine:latest
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/alpine ... latest: Pulling from 
library/alpine
not found
Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/library/alpine
```

Docker version:

```
# docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.9.1
 API version:     1.21
 Package version: docker-1.9.1-25.1.origin.el7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.4.2
 Git commit:      78ee77d/1.9.1
 Built:           
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.9.1
 API version:     1.21
 Package version: docker-1.9.1-25.1.origin.el7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.4.2
 Git commit:      78ee77d/1.9.1
 Built:           
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
```

Docker search output:

```
# docker search alpine
INDEX       NAME                                             DESCRIPTION                                     STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
docker.io   docker.io/alpine                                 A minimal Docker image based on Alpine Lin...   2818      [OK]       
docker.io   docker.io/mhart/alpine-node                      Minimal Node.js built on Alpine Linux           323                  
docker.io   docker.io/frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8             The smallest Docker image with OracleJDK 8...   269                  [OK]
docker.io   docker.io/anapsix/alpine-java                    Oracle Java 8 (and 7) with GLIBC 2.23 over...   253                  [OK]
docker.io   docker.io/gliderlabs/alpine                      Image based on Alpine Linux will help you ...   171
```

Comment: What does docker search of that particular image returns?

Comment: docker search returns search results from docker.io, updated the question to reflect the output.

Comment: Please update your docker version to latest stable and try once as 1.9 is too old. I think, it's a problem with signing certificates by unknown authority... or you could probably resolve as mentioned here https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26295

Comment: Thanks @mohan08p. But I finally found what was happening in this case. At some point in time the node ran out of disk space, and eventually recovered, however docker pull operations during that time caused the docker engine to write incomplete entries to /var/lib/docker/repositories-devicemapper file. And even after the disk space was recovered, docker was unable to recover. Fix for this was to remove /var/lib/docker/repositories-devicemapper; service docker stop; service docker start. But I take your suggestion to upgrade the docker service to latest version.